# MS Teams samples not sending messages to listening bot application

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When following MS Teams bot samples, I am unable to get any messages from Teams to reach my hosted applications.

Following the [MS Teams sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node) - this is the best way to reproduce the problem.

I ran the project and obtained the endpoint as `https://kindly-ash.glitch.me/api/messages`.

Registered this on the [bot framework site](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new) - with Webchat as well as MS Teams.

[image]

When sending a message from MS Teams, no requests were reaching the listening Node application.

[image]

When sending a message using the [bot framework site's webchat](https://dev.botframework.com/bots), a request does reach the listening Node application, but errors out.

```
(node:648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request to 'https://state.botframework.com/v3/botstate/webchat/conversations/873ec470c2fe4cf687c186d31c2b17f4/users/873ec470c2fe4cf687c186d31c2b17f4' failed: [405] Method Not Allowed

    at Request._callback (/app/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js:523:46)

    at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)

    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)

    at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)

    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)

    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)

    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)

    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)

(node:648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

In addition to the above, I have tried these samples locally and exposing via ngrok, I've also tried hosting on my own servers. I have also tried deleting and recreating bots, removing and re-adding channels.

When testing directly via the Bot Framework Emulator, the message is always received.

I'm unable to tell if MS Teams is not sending requests out, or the Bot Framework site is at fault.  Can anyone tell me where I may be missing something in the setup work?

Comment: Did you follow the [step #4](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node#fastest-way-to-see-this-project-in-action) and set the App Id and App password in .env file? Could you please share your Bot Id?

Comment: Hi @Wajeed-MSFT yes I did add those values to the .env.  I have recreated a new bot today, same sample code.  Handle is `my-test-bot-7` and AppID is 
`48177a29-d974-464c-b7b5-a50c20aa6698`.   Today when I send messages from Teams, I am getting the "HTTP 405" error (Method not allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because [Bot State Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) is deprecated. For testing you could use [In Memory Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#in-memory-data-storage). 
Please update code in **src/Bot.ts** inside constructor to set In Memory Storage like this:

```
constructor(private _connector: teams.TeamsChatConnector,private botSettings: any,) {
    super(_connector, botSettings);
    this.set("persistConversationData", true);

    var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();    
    this.set('storage', inMemoryStorage);
```

Please have a look at documentation on how to [Manage state data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). For production please use [Custom Data Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#manage-custom-data-storage).

Comment: We think this is happening because while the [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node) has been updated to use in-memory storage, which fixes this problem. But when you click on "remix on glitch" it's referencing an older version. We are validating this now and will update here once we've verified that it works.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT and Wajeed-MSFT thanks, it's just as you said.  Adding the inmemory bit worked and now messages are being received and responded to from MS Teams.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try again - we think we've fixed the problem.